# How to find all users that are in a location

Tags: scala

I have a collection of users:

```
case class User(id: Int, locationId: Int)

val users: List[User] = ....

val locationIds = List(1231,34323,3452)
```

How can I find all users that are in the locationIds?

```
val usersInLocation = users.map(_.locationId == ??)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
users.filter(user => locationIds.contains(user.locationId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter would probably be useful
val usersInLocation = users.filter(_.locationId == 1)
Let's say you have: 
Users[{name:'john', locationId: 1}, {name: 'mike', locationId: 2}, {name: 'jenny', locationId: 1}]

With the filter above usersInLocation would result in 
usersInLocation = [{name:'john', locationId: 1}, {name: 'jenny', locationId: 1}]

Comment: I have a list of locationIds, not a single locationId